# .htaccess remove index.php remove www. force https

Tags: .htaccess, indexing

I understand this is not necessarily an EE specific question, but it involves the classic EE removal of index.php from the URL as well as a couple more specific rewrites. It’s also a lazy question, as I’ve tried a few rewrite rule combinations and there are errors… so, what I’m after is (please).

- Remove www.
- Force https://
- Remove index.php

The important note, is that on an (mt) Media Temple server when testing on subdomains such as dev.domain.com the good old *multiple redirects* problem is kicking in. Ideally there’s a way for one .htaccess file to rule them all. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about apache settings, not EE settings.

Comment: Can you show your existing .htsccess?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove the www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#Remove index.php
#strip index.php from the URL if that is all that is given
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NS,L,QSA]
#strip index.php/* from the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]


# EE
#rewrite all non-image/js/css urls back to index.php if they are not files or directories
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|templates|themes)/ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Looks great @pvledoux and I thank you. However (and perhaps I should have mentioned) on the dev. server this gets the old *too many redirects* problem… do you know how to make this work with subdomains (for dev and staging)?

Comment: Probably a redirection loop, due to https (do you https on dev box?)

Comment: I don’t, because I’m a MAMP luddite, but I’m testing the code by quickly uploading .htaccess to dev. and seeing results there. Where the loop kick in, is it possible to detect subdomains and cope?

Comment: I'd say that this command would cause loop if www is entered, because first command forces https while in same time second line puts back http...

Comment: I can confirm it loops when www in front. so: sorry, doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (excluding the index.php part, only for removing WWW and forcing HTTPS), was this:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Remove the www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force https, specify http_host
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#-----the following part is untested, but should work to answer the full quesiton including the index.php part

#Remove index.php
#strip index.php from the URL if that is all that is given
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NS,L,QSA]
#strip index.php/* from the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]


# EE
#rewrite all non-image/js/css urls back to index.php if they are not files or directories
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|templates|themes)/ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/js/.*$

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/.*$

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/.*$

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fonts/.*$

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]    

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/themes/.*$

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/inc/.*$

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin.php$

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]    

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$ 

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```